# how to connect nexys2 FPGA with camera? Driver issue

Tags: image-processing, fpga

My project is to capture images and process them to move a wheelchair accordingly. I am using Nexys2 FPGA board for this purpose. Nexys2 has a usb port and the camera is also a usb camera. but i dont have the drivers in verilog which will make nexys2 and the camera communicate with each other. Please help me ill be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you manage to write a driver for a USB camera in VErilog, you can sell that for a lot of money :)
Well, sarcasm aside, there is NO WAY you can access a USB camera in Verilog, unless you have a USB host implemented in your FPGA and have a CPU controlling it and have a SW driver for that camera. 
There are alternatives to this, you can buy a camera which has an FPGA "friendly" connector like this one:
[5 Mega Pixel Digital Camera Package](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&No=281)
Which comes with the Verilog code that you can use in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the USB port on the Digilent Nexus 2 board does not have host capabilities, it can only act as a USB slave. The USB connection on the board is used for powering the board and configuring the FPGA and other onboard peripherals.
The newer Nexus 3 board has a second USB port however it has the same issue in that it can only act in slave mode. Also due to the configuration can only be used for mouse and keyboard input.